# ASP.NET active users count and tracking user activity

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, user-tracking

I need some help. Someone please tell me the best way to track user activity (ASP.NET website.) I need to manage list of all active users and find out the current page the users have opened. For example if user A is on Registration page then I need this information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to handle every page request and update a field in the DB e.g. `LastPageVisited` for that particular user.

This should be relatively straightforward to do with a [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ff8w4a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or if you are using MVC a [global action filter](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx).

Comment: what if the user closes his/her internet browser. How can I set isActive key to false?

Comment: @fwd unfortunately you can't reliably deal with the scenario where the user closes their browser. The best you can do is set the `IsActive` key to `false` when their session expires.